# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable in map function

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

Sorry I'm a newbie python coder.
I wrote this code in PyCharm:

```
lst_3 = [1, 2, 3]

def square(lst):
    lst_1 = list()
    for n in lst:
        lst_1.append(n**2)

    return lst_1


print(list(map(square,lst_3)))
```

and i have this type of error : TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable. 
What is the error in my code?

Comment: I see the code you posted has a strange indentation, can you fix that?

Comment: `map` has a function operate on each element - a scalar in your case.

Comment: When you `map` `square` to `lst_3`, each number is passed to `square` in turn. You don't need to _iterate_ over a number.

Comment: You can do `list(map(lambda x: x**2, lst_3))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue here is your misunderstanding of what `map` is doing. Here's a representative example. I've created an "identity" function of sorts which just echoes a number and returns it. I'll `map` this function to a list, so you can see what's printed out:

```
In [382]: def foo(x):
     ...:     print('In foo: {}'.format(x))
     ...:     return x
     ...: 

In [386]: list(map(foo, [1, 2, 3]))
In foo: 1
In foo: 2
In foo: 3
Out[386]: [1, 2, 3]
```

Notice here that *each element* in the list is passed to `foo` *in turn*, by `map`. `foo` does not receive a list. Your mistake was thinking that it did, so you attempted to iterate over a *number* which resulted in the error you see.

What you need to do in your case, is define `square` like this:

```
In [387]: def square(x):
     ...:     return x ** 2
     ...: 

In [388]: list(map(square, [1, 2, 3]))
Out[388]: [1, 4, 9]
```

`square` should work under the assumption that it receives a scalar.

Alternatively, you may use a `lambda` to the same effect:

```
In [389]: list(map(lambda x: x ** 2, [1, 2, 3]))
Out[389]: [1, 4, 9]
```

Keep in mind this is the *functional programming* way of doing it. For reference, it would be cheaper to use a list comprehension:

```
In [390]: [x ** 2 for x in [1, 2, 3]]
Out[390]: [1, 4, 9]
```